# Is there a way to classify a batch of images with the pretrained Inception-v3 network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpgpu, image-recognition

I'm trying to classify images with TensorFlow.

In the [example code on GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/imagenet/classify_image.py#L172) is something like this:

```
predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
```

Now, I'm looking for a solution for classifying multiple images in one go, because I'd like to compute the classification on my GPU, and I don't want to move the images to the GPU one by one, as that decreases performance.

A loop over all images around the `sess.run(...)` didn't do what I wanted: Every image was still sent to the GPU individually.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')
    for image in images:
        predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {'DecodeJpeg:0': image})
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at Google's github for their [Inception](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/inception) Deep CNN Classifier.

By following their guide, I was able to fine-tune the network to classify wine bottle labels.  You can classify many images in one run by just setting a larger batch size.

The whole guide is helpful, but you'd probably be especially interested in [Fine-Tuning a Pre-Trained Model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/inception#how-to-fine-tune-a-pre-trained-model-on-a-new-task)
.

Comment: Yes. I'll just point out that the guide [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/image_retraining/index.html) (as of today) uses an older version of the graph, where the shapes of the ops only take one image at a time. The tar-ball of inception referenced in @alamost52's guide is a newer one.

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of trial and error I found a solution which has the right behavior for me.
But I'm not sure if it's the most elegant one.

```
pool = ThreadPool()

def operation(sess, softmax, image, image_number):
    prediction = sess.run(softmax, {'DecodeJpeg:0': image})
    return prediction, image_number

with tf.Graph().as_default() as imported_graph:
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

with tf.Session(graph=imported_graph) as sess:
    with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
        softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')
        threads = [pool.apply_async(operation, args=(sess, softmax_tensor, np_images[image_number], image_number,)) for
                   image_number in range(len(np_images))]
        result = []
        for thread in threads:
            result.append(thread.get())
```

The key was to use a multithreading solution.

Answer (score 0):

Faced with the same task. The valid solution is feed model with batches of images as described here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images

You create a pipeline using tf.data package and feed. 
Take a note that in the tutorial there is eager mode, while it is no problem to do the same in a 'normal' mode.